# Non-uniqueness of loop-erasure for continuous-time curves

Tags: pr.probability, ca.classical-analysis-and-odes

**Question.** Is there a continuous curve in the plane that has a non-unique loop-erasure?

Here is the definition of a loop-erasure. A continuous curve $Y:[c,d]\to\mathbb R^2$ is a loop-erasure of a curve $X:[a,b]\to\mathbb R^2$ if there exists an increasing and right-continuous function $w:[c,d]\to [a,b]$ such that:

- $w(c)=a$,
- $X(w(d))=X(b)$,
- $Y(t)=X(w(t)), \forall t$,
- For every $T$, the image of the curve $Y(t), c\leq t\leq T$ does not intersect the image of the curve $X(s), w(T)<s\leq b$.

Note that if $w$ has a jump at time $t$, then one should have $X(w(t^-))=X(w(t))$. This corresponds to erasing a loop in $X$.

**Update.** Two loop-erasures are equivalent if they have the same image.

Comment: Couldn't two erasers of $X$ erase different loops of $X$?

Comment: @JochenWengenroth No, the definition implies that $Y$ should not intersect itself. So, for instance, if $X$ has finitely many self-intersections, then one should erase all of the loops and there is a unique loop-erasure.

Comment: Okay, I see now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The paper that Iosif Pinelis mentioned in his answer has an example to this problem: Consider the compact space obtained by adding $\pm\infty$ to the strip $\{ z\in \mathbb C: 0\leq \mathrm{Im}(z)\leq 1\}$. Consider the curve that connects the integer points of this set (by segments) in the following order: $\ldots, n, n+1, n+i, n+i+1, n+1, n+2,n+i+1,n+i+2,n+2,\ldots$. Then there are two non-equivalent loop-erasures of this curve: One has image $\mathbb R\cup\{\pm\infty\}$ and one has image $(\mathbb R+i)\cup\{\pm\infty\}$.

*Zhan, Dapeng*, [**Loop-erasure of planar Brownian motion**](http://dx.doi.org/10.1007/s00220-011-1234-9), Commun. Math. Phys. 303, No. 3, 709-720 (2011).

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/136788)

Comment: @AndrásBátkai According to your comment, I edited my answer and included the example here.

Answer (score 0):

$\newcommand\tt{\tilde t}\newcommand\tY{\tilde Y}\newcommand\tw{\tilde w}$A loop-erasure is never unique whenever it exists (see e.g. [this paper](https://documentcloud.adobe.com/link/review?uri=urn:aaid:scds:US:8de0e239-5b86-4492-94a4-eeb44ec3f322#pageNum=1) for a nontrivial example of such an existence):

*Zhan, Dapeng*, [**Loop-erasure of planar Brownian motion**](http://dx.doi.org/10.1007/s00220-011-1234-9), Commun. Math. Phys. 303, No. 3, 709-720 (2011). [ZBL1217.60076](https://zbmath.org/?q=an:1217.60076).

Indeed, if a continuous curve $Y\colon[c,d]\to\mathbb R^2$ is a loop-erasure of a curve $X\colon[a,b]\to\mathbb R^2$, witnessed by a function $w\colon[c,d]\to[a,b]$, then for any real $s$ the curve $[c-s,d-s]\ni\tt\mapsto\tY(\tt):=Y(s+\tt)$ is also a loop-erasure of the curve $X$, witnessed by the function $[c-s,d-s]\ni\tt\mapsto\tw(\tt):=w(s+\tt).$

Comment: I forgot to say that such examples are considered equivalent. I will update the question. But the paper that you mentioned has already an example for my question! Thanks.